# Enable startup pin/password security without lock screen pin/password?

Tags: security, lock-screens, boot, password

It is my intention to disable the pin/password for the lock screen, while still having the startup pin/password security.

As I understand it, the options are to set a pin/password for

- lock screen
- lock screen + startup

I'm trying to figure out how to do it for the *startup* only.

<sub>(My device starts fine without unlocking the SIM, despite the SIM card lock option being enabled.)</sub>

Comment: What's your phone? I've never heard something like a startup password.

Comment: @iBug My take is it is about the pre-boot authentication for decryption.

Comment: @Firelord [*beeshyams*'s answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/180424/205764)

Comment: @iBug Oukitel K10000, but I think it's a stock 6.0 feature. It asks for it when setting the lock for the lock screen. https://i.imgur.com/CRbdABZ.png